# Can't login to Windows 7 Home Premium even from safe mode and from the command prompt

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore, password-recovery

I use Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on my computer. Previously there was no problem. I have a new computer that I bought less than a year ago. I used it as usual, but when I opened it again the next day, I couldn't login to Windows, I wasn't recognized as an administrator, the password failed and access was denied.

Then I tried to get in through safe mode, deleted the password, opened Regedit, and I saw that there was a .bak file in the profile. After searching the internet, I tried to create a new profile and remove the duplicate file, but I still couldn't login. Then I returned it back to its original position from safe mode again. I could login to my computer in safe mode. I didn't find all the data I had stored on the computer. Then I opened the local disk [ C ] -> users -> homepremium  where I found all my files without any loss. But in the users folder, I saw my profile had duplicated up to 7 profiles >> user.temp.001 - 007.

I used my computer as usual while backing up my data. The Windows Update updated automatically (I didn't change any settings), The next day I couldn't login anymore. It said the group policy client service failed the logon. Access denied. I tried to get in through safe mode as before, but I couldn't, just login and then log out, and repeat. I tried to get in through safe mode from the command prompt to open System Restore, but I also couldn't, just login and then log out.

What should I do? I haven't finished backing up all the data that is stored in my computer because my external hard drive was damaged (I backed up the data to a DVD). I can't lose my data again (with my external hard drive broken) because I have important files. Please help.

Comment: You really shouldn't modify the Hive if you don't understand what you are doing, and removing your password by hand, is a great way to prevent any access to the account.  If your unable to enable the default Administrator account there isn't much hope for that particular installation of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting your files out could be to use a Linux LiveCD to copy copy your files from the windows disk to a USB disk. I have used Ubuntu for this. Then you can reinstall windows. Then you start doing proper backups.

Comment: Okayy~ I'll try that.. Thanks a lot :)